# Magento 2 knockoutJs can't find method

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

I asked a similar issue the other day but...oh sh*t here we are agin !

I'm in `src/vendor/magento/module-offline-payments/view/frontend/web/template/payment/checkmo.html`

I'm trying to figure it out where is the getTitle() called method in order to make some log inside.

```
<label data-bind="attr: {'for': getCode()}" class="label">
    <span data-bind="text: getTitle()"></span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume the checkmo component either uses or extends `app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/default.js` which does contain `getTitle`:

```
    /**
     * Get payment method type.
     */
    getTitle: function () {
        return this.item.title;
    },
```

See https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/7c6b6365a3c099509d6f6e6c306cb1821910aab0/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/default.js#L204

Comment: Thank you very much, Indeed, I missed it : `define([
    'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default'
], `